# BitRock exclude directory

Tags: bitrock

I am attempting to exclude the directory 
/Library/WebServer/Documents/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/.git

from my installer, but I am not having success.

```
<distributionFileList>
    <distributionDirectory>
        <allowWildcards>1</allowWildcards>
        <excludeFiles>.git</excludeFiles>
        <origin>/Library/WebServer/Documents/PHP-Point-Of-Sale</origin>
    </distributionDirectory>
</distributionFileList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wildcards, try the following code snippet:

```
<distributionFileList>
    <distributionDirectory>
        <allowWildcards>1</allowWildcards>
        <excludeFiles>*/.git</excludeFiles>
        <origin>/Library/WebServer/Documents/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/*</origin>
    </distributionDirectory>
</distributionFileList>
```

Hope it helps